# SUM on values of duplicate row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a burning question. I am running a MYSQL query that returns rows with duplicate values in it. That's no problem because that's how we saved the data in the past. Now i want the label to stay the same, but the value (int) must be SUMMED. I have no clue how to do this. Can anybody help me please?

```
label    |count |
_________________
shelves  |15    |
pictures |39    |
chairs   |19    |
tables   |41    |
shelves  |49    |
Cabinets |16    |
```

So i want the count to be SUMMED in MYSL when the label is a duplicate. Your help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `SUM`, e.g.:

```
SELECT label, SUM(`count`)
FROM table
GROUP BY label;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select label,sum(`count`)
from table_name
group by label
```

Comment: Add a little explaining text.